# JTextField in swing out of bounds

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I was trying to create form using swing, but the created input field is out of bounds.

My code

```
   package lista_designer_1;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class lista_designer_2 extends JFrame {

        JTextField text1;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

             lista_designer_2 frame1 = new lista_designer_2();             
             frame1.setSize(450, 300); 
             frame1.setVisible(true);
        }

    public lista_designer_2() {
        super("Hello World");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                text1 = new JTextField();
                text1.setBounds(10, 10, 76, 21);
                add(text1);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

After running this code it looks like this:

[image: Code results]

How can i fix it?

Comment: You should start with [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use layout managment see [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
For examples see  [Swing Layout Examples](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit591-2004/Pages/layout-examples.html).

Example to use FlowLayout layout:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout ());
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setLayout(null); This will remove the LayoutManager from your JFrame which causes the textfield to appear linke this.

Comment: Please stop giving advice on Java layouts until you understand *why* that is bad advice.